# What is Hashed Index?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

MongoDB 2.4 has a new feature that i see everyone around is talking about, so here is my question (sorry if they are simple):

- Does MongoDB manage them without specifying the shard key? or does the admin choose the key?
- Are there any risks of being in a Hostspot problem, or disk IO lags since there is the word Hash and hash is something random?

Comment: You still need to specify a key, it hashs, internally (what MongoDB sees) the key. The hash index is designed to specifically stop the hot spot problem, being how it is built up I cannot have not seen any problems with it yet

Comment: so why not using from the begning an additional key MD5(a key), or it just add waste of space? and this as i read, it is painful for the disk reads, since it is randomized and not kept in memory?

Comment: Because it is heavier than finding a excellent shard key, you only need to hash when you got no better shard key than a monotonically increasing one like ObjectId

Comment: this hash is an MD5 or a SHA or a special hash algorithm ?

Comment: I am not totally aware of the internals on that front since I have not looked at the code but I believe it just be a straight md5 hash

Comment: so the idea is: i choose a shard key, and mongodb will not use the value of the key but the hash of the key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that you can create a hashed index on a field you want to use as the shard key that happens to give bad write distribution (for example, it's monotonically increasing and would create a hotspot on recent entries).

The hash stored in the hashed index is 64 bits of the 128 bit md5 hash.  The goal is to allow sharding by the hash value of the key without the application needing to know about the hashing mechanism.

You can find more information on this here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-internals/#sharding-hashed-shard-key-internals

Comment: thank you, what about this "For workloads where getting ranges of documents is more important (i.e. find recent documents from all users), other choices of shard key may be better suited." http://blog.mongodb.org/post/47633823714/new-hash-based-sharding-feature-in-mongodb-2-4

Comment: it depends on the type of queries that you will be making. If a large portion of them is by single shardkey value (by id) then you're fine, or if some or enough of them are by another (indexed) attribute.  The problematic case would be if you always query by "records in the range of this id to this id" - that wouldn't be able to use the hashed index.

Comment: and what about `_id` since mongodb adds indexes them automatically, will it add a shard index for them too automatically?

Comment: no, it'll only add a regular index on _id.  You would need to add a hashed index on it as well for sharding.  You can have a regular and a hashed index on the same field.